# Passing variable from a function to a function within a function

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to create a chrome extension that takes a selected text via context menu, appends it to a url and update an existing tab (from the same domain) with the new URL.
This is my code:

```
function soso(search_target){
    alert(search_target);
    //search_target gets here successfully 

    chrome.tabs.query({
        url: "https://lightning.force.com/lightning/*"},
        function(tabs, search_target){

        if (tabs[0]){

            chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id, {
                url: "http://www.facebook.com"+search_target, //search_target doesnt get here
                active: true
            });
        }
        else{
            alert("no window");
        }
        });
}


function selectionHandler (info, tab)
{
        soso( info.selectionText);
}

function resetContextMenus ()
{
    chrome.contextMenus.removeAll(
    function()
    {
            var id = chrome.contextMenus.create( {
                title: "Open in Salesforce",
                contexts: [ "selection" ],
            onclick: selectionHandler
        } );
    }
    );
}
resetContextMenus();
```

The problem is that I cannot pass `search_target` to `chrome.tabs.update`, I get an `undefined` after the URL.

Any ideas on how to pass this variable?

Comment: Try to make another variable and append the data to new variable and try to pass that new appended variable to the url value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's move backwards with our analysis:

- you try to call `chrome.tabs.update`, passing `search_target`
- inside a callback `function` which has a `search_target` parameter
- the function is called by `chrome.tabs.query`
- and not by your outer `function`
- but you have a valid `search_target` in the outer context
- which is unreachable from the block of the callback `function` because a parameter with similar name which is undefined shadows it

Solution: Remove the parameter to allow the variable of the outer context be known inside the callback `function`:

```
function soso(search_target){
    alert(search_target);
    //search_target gets here successfully 

    chrome.tabs.query({
        url: "https://lightning.force.com/lightning/*"},
        function(tabs){

        if (tabs[0]){

            chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id, {
                url: "http://www.facebook.com"+search_target, //search_target doesnt get here
                active: true
            });
        }
        else{
            alert("no window");
        }
        });
}


function selectionHandler (info, tab)
{
        soso( info.selectionText);
}

function resetContextMenus ()
{
    chrome.contextMenus.removeAll(
    function()
    {
            var id = chrome.contextMenus.create( {
                title: "Open in Salesforce",
                contexts: [ "selection" ],
            onclick: selectionHandler
        } );
    }
    );
}
resetContextMenus();
```